# Evaluating $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}4} \log(1+\tan x)\,\mathrm dx$ using Leibniz rule of integrals

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I would love to get some insight on how to solve $\int_0^{\frac\pi4}\log(1+\tan x)\,\mathrm dx$ using Leibniz rule of integration. I know it can be solved using the property$$\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_a^bf((a+b)-x)\,\mathrm dx,$$but I find that method rather rigorous and am in search of a shorter elegant method.

Attached below is my attempt at doing it. I am unable to find $f(0)$ thus also the arbitrary constant.

[image]

My answer is $\dfrac π4\log(2)$, which is wrong. Please correct my method and show me the right way to do it.

p.s please excuse my code I am new to Mathjax.

Comment: Add dollar signs around your math to get it to display properly. For example, `$\int_a^bx^2dx$` displays as $\int_a^bx^2dx$.

Comment: thank you sir,will take note of that

Comment: When you evaluated $I^\prime(t)$, there shouldn't have been an overall $dt$ afterwards. Note that $I(t)=\frac{\pi}{4}\ln t+I(0)$, so $I^\prime(t)=\frac{\pi}{4t}$. Later, you give $I$ an $x$-dependent argument, even though $x$ is a dummy integration variable.

Answer (score 2):

Your choice of where to put the parameter results in significant problems, which I will illustrate with an example.  Suppose we are interested in computing
$$\int_{x=0}^{\pi/4} \log (1+x) \, dx.$$
If we introduce a parameter $t$ as you did, we have the function
$$I(t) = \int_{x=0}^{\pi/4} \log(t(1+x)) \, dx$$
Hence
$$I'(t) = \int_{x=0}^{\pi/4} \frac{1}{t(1+x)} \cdot (1+x) \, dx = \int_{x=0}^{\pi/4} \frac{1}{t} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{4t}.$$
Thus
$$I(t) = \int \frac{\pi}{4t} \, dt = \frac{\pi}{4} \log t + C$$
and we want to find $I(1)$.  But this is just $C$.  You've accomplished nothing, and this is because on the interval of integration,
$$\log (t(1+x)) = \log t + \log (1+x).$$  So you end up getting $\frac{\pi}{4t}$ no matter what function of $x$ you have in the logarithm, because it is lost after differentiation with respect to $t$.  Had the integrand been $$\log\left(\sin^2 (x + 1/x)  + 4x^{2059371} - 4/e^{x^2 + 1/x^{19}}\right),$$ you would still get the same result.  This means your choice of parametrization of the integrand is ineffective and you must try a different one.

Comment: thank you so much! now I got it

Answer (score 1):

You should let $ I(t)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln(1+t \tan x) dx,I=I(1),I(0)=0 $
$$ I'(t)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\tan x}{1+t \tan x} dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\sin x}{\cos x+t \sin x} dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left( \frac{t}{1+t^2}+\frac{-1}{1+t^2} \frac{-\sin x+t \cos x}{\cos x+t \sin x} \right) dx=\frac{\pi}{4} \frac{t}{1+t^2}+\frac{\ln 2}{2} \frac{1}{1+t^2} -\frac{\ln(1+t)}{1+t^2}$$

We note
$$ I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln(1+\tan x) dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(1+t)}{1+t^2} dt (\tan x =t) $$
Thus
$$ I=\int_{0}^{1}I'(t) dt =\int_0^1 \frac{\pi}{4} \frac{t}{1+t^2} dt+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln 2}{2} \frac{1}{1+t^2} dt -\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+t)}{1+t^2} dt $$
$$ I=\frac{\pi \ln 2}{4}-I $$
$$ I=\frac{\pi \ln 2}{8} $$

Comment: thanks for the help